# Is the layer value of MODIS Day_view_time and Night_view_time in Local Time or in Local Solar Time?

Tags: modis

On the [NASA homepage](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod11a1v006/) in the layer description you can find following line for the **Day_view_time** layer:[image]

Does this mean that the layer contains the Local Time (LT) in the corresponding local time zone or in Local Solar Time (LST)? 
And if this is the LST, is the difference significant if I'm not interested in the exact minute of the observation time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick reply. Look at the [MODIS Land Surface Temperature User Guide](https://icess.eri.ucsb.edu/modis/LstUsrGuide/usrguide.html)

For the Collection 5 product the answer to your question is in Table 4.
[image]

It says that the `View_time` attribute corresponds to the *local solar time*.

In the version of the User Guide for Collection 6 this information is in Table 3.

This attribute is specific to MODIS Land Surface Temperature MOD11_L2, MOD11A, MOD11B series of products.